PyInstaller causing a crash, PyCharm works a charm
I have someone else's Python code that I am upgrading from 3.7 to 3.12 before changing database calls to API calls. The Python code is compiled using PyInstaller into an executable to be distributed as required.
If I run the PyInstaller command, it compiles fine creating an executable and an "_internal" folder containing all of the files required (although the previous version had more files present in the same location as the executable. When I double click the executable, I get a runtime error which can be seen below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SourceCode\ODL\ODL_App.py", line 10, in <module>
    import core.core_utils
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "core\ODL_Method.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "als_microservices\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "als_microservices\aqc_stl.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 610, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\stats\_stats_py.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 293, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\sparse\_base.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\sparse\_sputils.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\_lib\_array_api.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\_lib\array_api_compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "numpy\f2py\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "numpy\f2py\crackfortran.py", line 159, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "numpy\f2py\auxfuncs.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "numpy\f2py\cfuncs.py", line 19, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Obviously I can see that the last line contains the crux of the error, but I do not know to which module or line within said module that applies to, as it references a number of modules.
Now when running through PyCharm, I can get the application running, although it times out at a database function, so I cannot see where the error occurs by stepping through the code.
If I enter in the command "python --version" within either the terminal of PyCharm or the Window by which I am instigating the PyInstaller, I get the same Python version. If I import sys and then do a print(sys.version) within the PyCharm Python window, I also get the same version.
Now this use to work when everything was running on Python 3.7, so I know it is down to either a mismatch of versions between Python and Modules, or something that has been deprecated or a function now changed.
The big question is: how do I narrow this down in order to resolve the issue.

The issue that I am seeing is very similar to the bug mentioned in this link: https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/8679

upgrading gives sometime errors. You may need to reinstall it (or in an virtual environment, but warning: conda (if you use it) may change some code (hooks) so have some alternate environment, because upgrades sometime go bad

I've amended the Python scripts as mentioned in the bug fix, I've ran the PyInstaller using a debug level of trace to see where it is grabbing the "numpy" functions etc from, and it would appear to be the same place as what I have fixed, but I still get the error. I'm not using Conda.

My experience: reinstall it (but before it, clean/move the old installation). Some leftover files (python objects, dll, or also python files) may be obsolete, but python will read them as the true files, without looking at where it was moved (refactored). (these are my frequent problems, but they may be other problems).

Although I amended the Python scripts within the environment folder of "venv", it was using the libraries held under my user at "james.grant/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/numpy". Was the code in there was amended, it compiled and worked perfectly.

This was a bug within the numpy library and acknowledged by its authors. Please view the link for detailed information: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/27021/commits/e10db14228067552b900b3399ea9bb1b552dd2d0
My issue was changing the library within the virtual environment didn't work as it was using the libraries held under my user account, I'm guessing these are the global libraries. To view what libraries your PyInstaller instance is using, pay close attention to when it is building the EXE to see where it is including the run-time hooks from.
